# ServiceStack "rememberme" and updating our web

Tags: servicestack

We updated our web site and service this morning and several users reported they couldn't log in.  For each user we've looked at, the login has worked a short time after they reported it.  We are looking to some type of caching as the possible culprit.

Is it possible that the "rememberme" setting during our servicestack authorization is causing a problem?  Might we be picking up an old session that isn't working with the newly compiled servicestack service?

Any other ideas someone might have would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an old session problem, you can verify that clearing the cookies cache from the client browser and refresh it.